# Why does my .net sdk style project show so many files in Solution Explorer?

Tags: c#, dotnet-sdk

I'm a newb to the SDK style project format
I only have a couple of NuGet PackageReferences. Everything was behaving normally up until some point when I think I had messed with my supported platforms / build configurations.

The build succeeds. But it's a pain to edit this thing in the IDE.
[image: solution explorer with false listing of files]

> Here's my *.csproj file contents:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net40;net48;</TargetFrameworks>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Authors>myself</Authors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net40|x86'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net40|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Accusoft.ImageGear.PDF" Version="24.14.0"   />
    <PackageReference Include="Accusoft.ImageGear.Recognition" Version="24.14.0"  />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Consoto.SimpleProj.Core\Consoto.SimpleProj.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Remove="Helpers.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Remove="README.md" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Remove="Properties\Settings.settings" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

> Here is the actual project directory:

[image: Windows File Explorer view of Project Directory]

Comment: Have you looked in your project directory or the build output?

Comment: I appended a picture so you can see it has very little in it